# How do I set up the Rich Text Editor Field (Redactor) for code snippets?

Tags: templating, redactor, richtext, editor

I'm trying to set us the Rich Text Editor for inputting code snippets. I've almost got it working except when I go back to edit the entry Redactor removes spaces I entered to format the code. Also setting the tabAsSpaces doesn't seem to work. It still adds tab space.

Here is what I have in Redactor config.json

```
{
    toolbar: false,
    visual: false,
    tabAsSpaces: 2,
    cleanOnPaste: false,
    cleanSpaces: false,
    cleanStyleOnEnter: true,
    paragraphize: false,
    minHeight: 200
}
```

And in the template

```
{% spaceless %}
<pre>
  <code>
    {{- block.html|replace({'&':'&amp;', '<':'&lt;', '>':'&gt;'})|raw -}}
  </code>
</pre>
{% endspaceless %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if it helps, but I accomplished this using a **plain text** field (with multi-line enabled). Then I just used CSS to format the field in a way to make it look like a code snippet...

**Screenshot of field in the Control Panel:**

[image: example code]

I used the [Control Panel CSS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss) plugin to add this CSS:

```css
#fields-myfieldhandle textarea.nicetext {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: Menlo, Monaco, monospace, sans-serif;
    color: #cccccc;
    background-color: #222222;
    padding: 14px 16px;
}
```

Then, in my Twig template, I display it like this:

```html
<pre><code>{{ block.code|e }}</code></pre>
```

May or may not be the solution you're looking for, but I've been very satisfied with it!

Comment: Thanks yes I have tested various ways and this works the best.